Why is a 32-bit integer necessary to store the 12-bit ADC reading instead of a 16-bit integer?
I previously encountered a problem here, where my 12-bit ADC readings sometimes contain a fixed error of around +/-255mV. Below is the `main.c' file, where the problem occurred:
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
 ******************************************************************************
 * @file           : main.c
 * @brief          : Main program body
 ******************************************************************************
 * @attention
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2024 STMicroelectronics.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
 * in the root directory of this software component.
 * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
 *
 ******************************************************************************
 */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim10;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM10_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
 * @brief  The application entry point.
 * @retval int
 */
int main(void) {

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    /* USER CODE END 1 */

    /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

    /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
    HAL_Init();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

    /* USER CODE END Init */

    /* Configure the system clock */
    SystemClock_Config();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

    /* USER CODE END SysInit */

    /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_ADC1_Init();
    MX_TIM10_Init();
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

    HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);

    /* USER CODE END 2 */

    /* Infinite loop */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    while (1) {
        /* USER CODE END WHILE */

        /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    }
    /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
 * @brief System Clock Configuration
 * @retval None
 */
void SystemClock_Config(void) {
    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = { 0 };
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = { 0 };

    /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
     */
    __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

    /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
     * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
     */
    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 25;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 360;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 2;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
    if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    /** Activate the Over-Drive mode
     */
    if (HAL_PWREx_EnableOverDrive() != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
     */
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
            | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

    if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}

/**
 * @brief ADC1 Initialization Function
 * @param None
 * @retval None
 */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void) {

    /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = { 0 };

    /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

    /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */

    /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
     */
    hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
    hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
    hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
    hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
    hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
    hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
    hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
    hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
    hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
    hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
    hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
    hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
    if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
     */
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
    sConfig.Rank = 1;
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_3CYCLES;
    if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

    /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
 * @brief TIM10 Initialization Function
 * @param None
 * @retval None
 */
static void MX_TIM10_Init(void) {

    /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM10_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE END TIM10_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM10_Init 1 */

    /* USER CODE END TIM10_Init 1 */
    htim10.Instance = TIM10;
    htim10.Init.Prescaler = 0;
    htim10.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    htim10.Init.Period = 3600 - 1;
    htim10.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    htim10.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim10) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM10_Init 2 */

    /* USER CODE END TIM10_Init 2 */

}

/**
 * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
 * @param None
 * @retval None
 */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void) {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
    /* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

    /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
    /* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

uint16_t adc_value;

void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef *hadc) {
    if (hadc == &hadc1) {
        adc_value = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);

        HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim10);
    }
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim) {
    if (htim == &htim10) {
        HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);
    }
}

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
 * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
 * @retval None
 */
void Error_Handler(void) {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
    /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
    __disable_irq();
    while (1) {
    }
    /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

The problem also occurs if I use DMA to write the 16-bit integer. Here, I set the ADC to be in continuous mode with continuous DMA request and DMA circular mode as shown in the code below:
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
 ******************************************************************************
 * @file           : main.c
 * @brief          : Main program body
 ******************************************************************************
 * @attention
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2024 STMicroelectronics.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
 * in the root directory of this software component.
 * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
 *
 ******************************************************************************
 */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_adc1;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim10;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM10_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

uint16_t adc_value;

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
 * @brief  The application entry point.
 * @retval int
 */
int main(void) {

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

    /* USER CODE END 1 */

    /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

    /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
    HAL_Init();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

    /* USER CODE END Init */

    /* Configure the system clock */
    SystemClock_Config();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

    /* USER CODE END SysInit */

    /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_DMA_Init();
    MX_ADC1_Init();
    MX_TIM10_Init();
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

    HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*) &adc_value, 1);

    /* USER CODE END 2 */

    /* Infinite loop */
    /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
    while (1) {
        /* USER CODE END WHILE */

        /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    }
    /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
 * @brief System Clock Configuration
 * @retval None
 */
void SystemClock_Config(void) {
    RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = { 0 };
    RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = { 0 };

    /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
     */
    __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

    /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
     * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
     */
    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 25;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 360;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 2;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLR = 2;
    if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    /** Activate the Over-Drive mode
     */
    if (HAL_PWREx_EnableOverDrive() != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
     */
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
            | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV4;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;

    if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_5) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
}

/**
 * @brief ADC1 Initialization Function
 * @param None
 * @retval None
 */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void) {

    /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 0 */

    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = { 0 };

    /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 1 */

    /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 1 */

    /** Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion)
     */
    hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
    hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
    hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
    hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
    hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
    hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
    hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
    hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
    hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
    hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
    hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = ENABLE;
    hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
    if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
     */
    sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
    sConfig.Rank = 1;
    sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_3CYCLES;
    if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN ADC1_Init 2 */

    /* USER CODE END ADC1_Init 2 */

}

/**
 * @brief TIM10 Initialization Function
 * @param None
 * @retval None
 */
static void MX_TIM10_Init(void) {

    /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM10_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE END TIM10_Init 0 */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM10_Init 1 */

    /* USER CODE END TIM10_Init 1 */
    htim10.Instance = TIM10;
    htim10.Init.Prescaler = 0;
    htim10.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
    htim10.Init.Period = 3600 - 1;
    htim10.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
    htim10.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim10) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM10_Init 2 */

    /* USER CODE END TIM10_Init 2 */

}

/**
 * Enable DMA controller clock
 */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void) {

    /* DMA controller clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* DMA interrupt init */
    /* DMA2_Stream0_IRQn interrupt configuration */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream0_IRQn);

}

/**
 * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
 * @param None
 * @retval None
 */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void) {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
    /* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

    /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
    /* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
 * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
 * @retval None
 */
void Error_Handler(void) {
    /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
    /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
    __disable_irq();
    while (1) {
    }
    /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

In both cases, only the main.c files contain the user code. The rest are all generated by the code generation of STM32CubeIDE.
The solution to my previous problem was to change the type of the variable that stores the reading to a 32-bit integer. However, this does not make sense to me as a 12-bit ADC reading should be in a range of [0, 4095], which should be within the 16-bit integer range of [0, 65535]. Any ideas what might be the cause to this weird error?

You have probably set the DMA transfer to be 32 bits wide, so it writes the ADC value to the 16-bit variable, and an adjacent 16-bit memory location - very dangerous! So carry on using a 32-bit variable, or change the DMA transfer width to 16. Also, calling a function to do a single DMA transfer is really inefficient, it'll be much quicker to just write the value to the variable.

Be clear that the posted error of +/-255 is related to converted voltage i.e. it's a +/-255 mV anomaly.

The bug is likely to be wherever you're doing something with the adv_value variable. We need to see that code too.

Please show your initialise code so that we can see how the ADC DMA has been configured

@brhans I have added the code for both single conversion and DMA continuous conversion that caused the problem. I did not use the ADC reading anywhere else.

@jayben The transfer width of DMA is set to a half word, which should be 32 / 2 = 16 bits if I understand the machine word size for STM32 correctly. The DMA code is added in the post. I agree with the single DMA transfer being inefficient. I only wanted to illustrate that the problem was also found in the DMA conversion mode.

You really shouldn't get surprised why 32 bit sized variables are used on a 32 bit CPU.

To keep the API consistent the architecture width (32 bit) is chosen.
Which is perfectly valid to pass this address.
Some STM32 parts put both ADC1 and ADC2 results in a single 32 bit register for DMA transaction, and when performing a 32 bit DMA transaction the start address must be 32-bit word aligned. (see reference manual)
If given address was a 16-bit type this alignment would not be guaranteed  and you could get an UsageFault UNALIGNED.
In you case you can cast your uint16_t to a uint32_t because the width of the transaction it only half-word. But only you know that! The library writers didn't.
In reality what often happens is that your adc_value is an array properly decorated with qualifiers.
eg: volatile uint16_t adc_value[64] __attribute__((aligned(8)));
The aligned attribute tells the linker to align on 8-byte boundary, such that even a cast to uint64_t remains valid. And the volatile quailifer tells the compiler the contents of this array may outside the predictable program flow.
Because using the DMA for only a single value is kind of useless (there is a ADC->DR already). Instead the DMA is used in circular mode in conjunction with the DMA half and complete interrupts to do something with a number of samples.

Thank you for the answer! Would it be reasonable to assume the same reasoning for the anomaly in the single conversion mode as well? i.e. reading the 32-bit ADC register into an unaligned 16-bit integer causes the same problem as the DMA case.

@PontakornPrasertsuk no, "The peripheral registers must be written at word level (32 bits). Read accesses can be done by bytes (8 bits), half-words (16 bits) or words (32 bits)." -- reference manual stm32f407

I see. Then I still don't understand why the anomaly exists in the single conversion mode as well. I guess I might need to investigate the assembly instructions to see what could be the cause

@PontakornPrasertsuk it is probably not an error in the aqcuisition, but in the display or processing.
